# Checkbox in Datagridview cannot be changed

Tags: c#, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I've created a Datagridview bound to a Datatable. This Datatable is updated by a event to reflect statistical information as it changes (sub second resolution). I have a checkbox to determine if a row is available for other functions and can be toggled on and off normally if my eventhandler is not receiving my updates.

If my bound Datatable is changed, the checkbox returns to its previous state as soon as the cursor or focus leaves the checkbox glyph (not the cell).

How do I toggle the checkboxes without them reseting without disconnecting my eventhandler?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid dataBinding. Manually create DataGridView rows. Then handle checkboxcell's events.